# How to combine transporter related blocks with Delay, Queues and other blocks from Process Modelling Library?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

A source is producing "productA". "productA" is moved by a transporter called "agv" from node1 to node2. On the way between the two nodes I want to put several tasks like for example delay or queue. These tasks can be implemented by Process Modelling Library blocks. When using them you have to set an agent type. Which type do I use now? "productA" or "agv"? When using "agv" an error accurs because that type is not equal to the source agent. When using "productA" tasks from the process Modelling blocks are only executed for this agent, not for "agv". How to deal with that? Is there a way to create a new agent which contains "productA" and "agv" and overwrites the source agent? How will that not contradict with the transporter fleet block?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ProductA` as this is the main agent flowing through the blocks. It just "uses" an `AGV` to be moved around, similar to a resource.

If you want to stop and do things with the product and the AGV, you use the `SeizeTransporter` block first, this makes your product seize an AGV.

Then, you can make them do anything by dropping blocks: queues, delays, `Move By Transporter`. Just make sure to finish up with a `Release Transporter` block when all is done.